# .bin firmware Standalone Binwalk returns garbage, Binwalk -I returns something but seems corrupted. Binwalk -X returns hundreds of raw deflate streams

Tags: firmware-analysis, binwalk

As the title says I have the firmware of the WAX214 wifi access point. The firmware is actively preventing me from using the full available functionality of the device so I am trying to reverse it to look for a way to get raw ssh shell on it.

From the running firmware I can deduce 100% that it is an Openwrt based system.

Running binwalk against it returns just two results, which are pretty much garbage.

```
┌──(arimodu㉿kalivm)-[~/WAX214-Firmware]
└─$ binwalk WAX214_V2.1.1.3_firmware.bin   

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11661818      0xB1F1FA        MPEG transport stream data
19693572      0x12C8004       Cisco IOS microcode, for ""
```

If I try to run Binwalk with the -I flag I get

```
┌──(arimodu㉿kalivm)-[~/WAX214-Firmware]
└─$ binwalk WAX214_V2.1.1.3_firmware.bin -I

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
27            0x1B            Broadcom firmware header Corporatio sfsM▒Üõvÿ. Model: <ãÖ¬5x<Ìg³Y´x<Ï!ß8ßUð¨GÝ8Â¦ÿWkH
                                                                                                                   ®Ïg³Y­Qÿ¨ÀY¬x<ÎÐ+HÏg³Y¯x<Åg³Y¬Pÿ¼*Ï. Firmware version: ß8ßUð¨GÝ8Â¦ÿWkH
                                                              ®Ïg³Y­Qÿ¨ÀY¬x<ÎÐ+HÏg³Y¯x<Åg³Y¬Pÿ¼*Ï.
30494         0x771E          Linux EXT filesystem, blocks count: 2183564478, image size: 2235970025472, invalid state invalid error behavior invalid major revision rev -1056396809.-16120, ext4 filesystem data, UUID=4a8b3f59-f0aa-15d2-358c-2d4ffbeffbef, volume name "*ØXwû¶G"
```

Which is more what I would expect but there are these "corrupted" parts.
If I try to extract that with dd I just get the same thing. Running file against the extracted "filesystem" I get

```
┌──(arimodu㉿kalivm)-[~/WAX214-Firmware]
└─$ file filesystem.ext4
filesystem.ext4: Linux rev -148578675.-16120 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=4a8b3f59-f0aa-15d2-358c-2d4ffbef33d6 (compressed) (extents) (huge files)
```

I notice the (compressed) keyword here so trying to run binwalk -X I get

```
┌──(arimodu㉿kalivm)-[~/WAX214-Firmware]
└─$ binwalk WAX214_V2.1.1.3_firmware.bin -X 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
18            0x12            Raw deflate compression stream
51            0x33            Raw deflate compression stream
53            0x35            Raw deflate compression stream
213           0xD5            Raw deflate compression stream
269           0x10D           Raw deflate compression stream
275           0x113           Raw deflate compression stream
429           0x1AD           Raw deflate compression stream
544           0x220           Raw deflate compression stream
700           0x2BC           Raw deflate compression stream
1100          0x44C           Raw deflate compression stream
1107          0x453           Raw deflate compression stream
1204          0x4B4           Raw deflate compression stream
1564          0x61C           Raw deflate compression stream
1940          0x794           Raw deflate compression stream
2836          0xB14           Raw deflate compression stream
3960          0xF78           Raw deflate compression stream
3995          0xF9B           Raw deflate compression stream
4084          0xFF4           Raw deflate compression stream
   .
   .
   .
```

I trimmed the output of this one but basically it goes through the entire file by some 50 - 200 or so increments.
I tried mounting, no luck. fsck no luck either. What I get from that is this is not usable as a filesystem. Its probably not encrypted, but there is certainly something going in with compression I dont understand. Strings against either doesnt come up with anything useful, just garbage.
Entropy is currently broken on kali and I cant seem to get it working so I didnt run entropy.

Any ideas of what might be happening here?

Comment: I am running into the same thing with a software pkg format I am trying to understand how they encrypted it. Binwalk -e comes up with two things some compressed gzip that is corrupted data stream and date tagged in the future, but what I know for sure is that I have an ext4 file system in that compressed image using the binwalk -I. Just starting to dump it via dd to figure it out but yes, would be interested if you got further.

Comment: @oldoperator Sorry, after posting this I never got further. I tried and tried again but never got further than this. If someone more experienced got in here it would be great.